# keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, –storepass is not a legal command

Tags: linux, keystore

I am getting following error when trying to run below command

> keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, –storepass is
>   not a legal comman

```
keytool -genkey -dname "CN=apptest2, OU=A, O=te ha,L=Delhi, S=Delhi, C=IN" -alias "ssocertificate" -keyalg RSA -keypass P@ssw0rd -keystore /etc/cas/certificate/portal.keystore –storepass storepass -keyalg "RSA" -ext SAN=dns:apptest2,ip:105.210.22.145
```

I tried to add `double quotes""` for `storepass` but same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (as the error clearly states), that the program doesn't know the option `–storepass` (rather than the argument to that option).

Now the dash `–` that starts that argument looks suspiciously like an m-dash, rather than a minus-sigen `-` as expected by any standard argument parser.

So you should use `-storepass` rather than `–storepass`

Comment: Thanks now its saying Illegal option: `Illegal option:  -ext
  
Try keytool -help`